# PrimeVue FileUpload component shows "Completed" even when the file upload fails

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file-upload, vuejs3, primevue

I'm working with the PrimeVue **FileUpload** component in my Vue.js application, and I'm encountering an issue where the component displays "Completed" even when the file upload to the specified URL fails.

I have configured the **FileUpload** component as follows:

```
<FileUpload
  name="demo[]"
  :fileLimit="1"
  url="/api/image"
  @upload="uploadImage"
  :multiple="false"
  accept="image/*"
  :maxFileSize="1000000"
/>
```

And here is the **uploadImage** function:

```
const uploadImage = async (event) => {
  try {
    const response = event.xhr;
    
    if (response.status === 200) {
      // Handle successful upload
    } else {
      // Handle upload failure
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error handling upload:', error);
    // Handle any other errors or exceptions here
  }
};
```

The issue is that even when the file upload to the /api/image URL fails (e.g., due to a server error or network issue), the FileUpload component still displays "Completed" to the user. This can be misleading as the upload was not actually successful.

I've also attached two screenshots to illustrate the issue. In one screenshot, the file upload succeeds, and in the other, it fails, but in both cases, the "Completed" text is displayed.
**Screenshot 1: Before Upload**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYkTb.png)
**Screenshot 2: Failed Upload (Issue)**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTfdC.png)

I would appreciate any guidance on how to make the **FileUpload** component accurately reflect the upload status and not display "**Completed**" when the upload fails. Is there a way to handle this scenario correctly?
**
Thank you for your help!**

**What I've Done:**

I'm using the PrimeVue **FileUpload** component in my Vue.js application to allow users to upload files. I've configured the component with the appropriate attributes, including **fileLimit**, **url**, and event handlers.

I've implemented the **uploadImage** function to handle the file upload and respond based on the HTTP status code of the response.

**What I'm Expecting:**

I expect that when the file upload to the specified **URL** (/api/images) fails due to reasons such as server errors or network issues, the **FileUpload** component should accurately reflect the upload status. Specifically, it should not display "**Completed**" when the upload is unsuccessful.

I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure that the **FileUpload** component correctly displays the upload status, avoiding the "Completed" message when an upload fails.